# Can't get my selected list item to show up in another page. {Error: Unable to get property 'title' of undefined or null reference}

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I am new at programming and I know there is probably a simple solution, but I'm stuck. I was following a CRUD Ionic tutorial but I want to implement some of my own changes. I am having a hard time getting a single list item to go from the Movies page to the Details page when I click on a single movie. The data does not load and I am getting an error message: `Unable to get property 'title' of undefined or null reference`
Here are my .html & .ts files:

**details.html**

```html
<ion-item *ngIf="movie" (click)="showOptions(movie.$key, movie.title)">
  {{this.title}} 
  {{this.date}}
  {{this.duration}}
  {{this.summary}}
</ion-item>
```

This is what I'm using to try to get the data from the "movies" page and display it in my details page -

**details.ts**

```
{
this.movies = aDB.list('/movies');
// this.movies = navParams.get('movie');
// Also tried using ^this function to *get the selected movie info.
}
```

What I'm trying to use to pass in the data is:

**movies.html**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let movie of movies | async" (click)="itemTapped($event, movie.title)">
    {{movie.title}} 
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**movies.ts**

```js
itemTapped(event, movie) {
  this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage, {item: movie});
}
```

I also tried this to push the code over to the details.html page.

```js
itemTapped(movies) {
  this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage)
};
```

Yes, I have checked the docs for Angular, Ionic & Firebase. Please, help would be much appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In **movies.html**

Replace this code block

```
(click)="itemTapped($event, movie.title)
```

with this

```
(click)="itemTapped($event, movie)
```

Comment: I still cannot see it show up in my details.html page when I click.

Comment: @ChristinaPhillips, will you please set a plunker for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to fix this problem. The problem in my code was that I couldn't get my data to show up on another page when an item in my list was displayed. Here is the solution that I used:

This code would display the list and select individual items when they are clicked on.

```
      <button ion-item *ngFor="let movie of movies | async" (click)="openmovieDetail(movie)">
    <ion-thumbnail item-left>
      <img src="{{movie.thumbnail}}"/>
    </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2>{{ movie.title }}</h2>
      <p>{{ movie.year }} - {{ movie.genre }} ∙ {{ movie.length }}</p>
  </button>
```

Then in my `.ts` file, the function that I used to capture the individual data and push it over to the details page was

```
    openmovieDetail(movie: any) {
      console.log(movie);
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage, movie);
}
```

I was able to `console.log(movie);` and display it with this html:

```
<ion-content padding>
      <ion-item *ngIf="movie" (click)="showOptions(movie.$key, movie)">
       <img src="{{movie.poster}}"/>
        <ion-card-content>
          <h2 class="card-title">{{ movie.title }}</h2>
          <p>{{ movie.year }}, {{ movie.genre }}</p>
        </ion-card-content>
```

This worked like a charm. Hope this can help someone else.